# Prevent duplicate form submission in liferay

Tags: liferay

I am facing the problem of duplicate form submission.
I kept `<action-url-redirect>true</action-url-redirect>` in `liferay-portlet.xml`.

My portlet gets hanged up and I am not able to perform any action.
I am using Liferay MVC portlet. Any solution apart from redirect.

Comment: For what property did you set `true` in `liferay-portlet.xml`?

Comment: I got it, after editing you question.

Comment: Have you placed `<action-url-redirect>true</action-url-redirect>` right after `<icon>` tag in `liferay-portlet.xml`?

Comment: [***Reference***](http://liferaytutorial.blogspot.com/2013/11/avoiding-multiple-submitsrefresh-page.html)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site (please add the appropriate information - on both ends)

Comment: yes exactly after icon tag. My portlet stopped working , and it is taking more time even to load